# Integral Using Partial Fraction Decomposition

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

So I have the integral of (4x^2+2x-1)/(x^3+x^2), and I have to solve it using partial fraction decomposition. The only thing is, the way I set it up, I need another factor for x to make it equal one of my variables that I made and I'm not sure how to get it or if I set up the problem wrong. [Here is the work I've done on the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayGB6.jpg)

Comment: The equation holds for all $x$, so any choice will do.

Comment: The so-called “cover up method” does not finish the job when you have repeated roots.

Comment: You could always just equate the coefficients of different powers of $x$